# Is there a way to catch a parked domain as a referrer

Tags: php, redirect, dns

We have 100's of parked domain from the registrar. And We have redirected it to mypersonaldomain.com. My aim is to determine what parked domain has redirected to mypersonaldoimain.com and then forward the user to myperosnaldomain.com/info-

We have already set a sample parked domain to redirect to mypersonaldomain.com however the parked domain did not register to the $_SERVER referrer.

Comment: How are you redirecting?

Comment: i am not the one who set the redirection... But my client probably set  it at the parked domain option from the registrar.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass domain name with redirection as in mypersonaldomain.com?d=Myprevdomain.com. if it is a 301 redirection.

If it is just pointing the domain to your target server domain. then you can capture it from CAPTURE_URI.

It only records http_referer if a user click a link to your new server, in this way browser sends http_referer .  or if you send the header http_referer when redirecting.